# Installing TensorFlow examples in EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I am currently running on Amazon EC2 instance and am trying to run the following code in a Jupyter Notebook (Python 2.7):

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/")
images, labels = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels
images = images.reshape((55000,28,28))
np.savez_compressed("MNIST_data/train", images=images, labels=labels)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-de596f1c663d> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
      3 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/")
      4 images, labels = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels
      5 images = images.reshape((55000,28,28))

ImportError: No module named tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist
```

Up until now, I have not had to install any libraries in order to get TensorFlow code to work (and I'm not exactly sure why I haven't needed to install anything).  How do I install this example set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, the following,

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
```

should work, I just double-checked. Maybe you have a very old TensorFlow version installed? You can check the version via

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

I don't remember when `input_data` was added to `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist` but it should work with either Tf 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: Hey Sebastian -- thanks for your quick answer.  Running the version check returns a "no module named Tensorflow" error.  It turns out that my Amazon instance comes pre-installed with Theano, but not TensorFlow. Do you know what I'd do to get TensorFlow installed with Python 2.7 in my instance?

Comment: I typically use my own AMI from the Ubuntu instances, and I don't know how exactly they set it up. However, if you are lucky, it could be as simple as executing `pip install tensorflow-gpu` from the command line. Alternatively, you could try out the DL AMI mentioned in the other answer. Or if you want to setup a DL instance/AMI on AWS yourself, here would be a step by step guide: https://sebastianraschka.com/pdf/books/dlb/appendix_h_cloud-computing.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the AWS DeepLearning AMI which comes with TensorFlow (among other MachineLearning packages) installed.

> The AMI Ids for the Deep Learning Amazon Linux AMI are the following:
>   us-east-1: ami-4b44745d
>   us-east-2: ami-305d7c55
>   us-west-2: ami-296e7850
>   eu-west-1: ami-d36386aa
>   ap-southeast-2: ami-52332031
>   ap-northeast-1: ami-b44050d3
>   ap-northeast-2: ami-1523fc7b
>
> Release tags/Branches used for the DW Frameworks:
>   MXNet : v0.10.0 tag
>   **TensorFlow : v1.1.0 tag**
>   Theano : rel-0.8.2 tag
>   Caffe : rc5 tag
>   Caffe2: v0.7.0
>   Keras : 1.2.2 tag
>   CNTK : v2.0.rc1 tag
>   Torch : master branch

See the [description](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB) to know more about it